# List/Library view threshold alert with filter on indexed column

Tags: list-view, library, threshold

According the folowing elements :

- The library view threeshold is at 39000 elements (configured at farm level)
- The library contain 50000 elements
- We created a view with a filter on an indexed column who match with just one item
- On the site collection side, the search works good

However i still have the alert in spite of the use of this view : the view cannot be displayed because it exceeds the list view threshold…
Do you have any idea where this might have come from?

Best regards,
Bastien

Answer (score 0):

ok so you are using on prem. The issue may be your index. If I remember correctly there is was an issue where the index creation failed (because a list was already beyond the threshold) but it was showing in the library/list indexed columns.

Try this.

1. Increase the list view threshold to 51K.
2. Remove the index.
3. Create index again.
4. Reduce the list view threshold back to 39K.

Test the view again.

Another thing to try (it worked on SP2010/2013) is to add another clause to your view. AND ID >0. (don't ask me why but for some reason this clause quite often resolved issue with list view threshold error message. And I had same situation as you), maybe even try that as first option.